# C# .net assembly causes ambiguous error when used in VB.NET`

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-assembly

I have a C# .NET assembly that implements a function that returns an int and an overload that returns an Int32.

```
public int GetAudioInputLevel()
public Int32 GetAudioInputlevel()
```

If I use the assembly from a C# .NET application and call that function, it works fine.

If I call my assembly's function from a vb.NET application, I get the following error :

> Error [myfunctionname] is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members
>   with this name exist in class '[myassemblysclass] ...

Can someone suggest a workaround, to use that function in vb.net without having to change the signature of that function in my c# .net assembly ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the exact signatures of the 2 methods?

Comment: An int and an Int32 are the same thing (int is an alias for Int32).  VB is not a case-sensitive language, like C# is.  That's likely the problem.  Can you post the method signatures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET is not case-sensitive, so these are the same methods, as far as the language is concerned.  You'll need to either change the name of one of them or add a parameter, which would change the method signature enough so that it's different.  However, don't add a parameter just to add one.

It *is* confusing, though, because int and Int32 are the same thing even though they don't look it.  A `long` is also an alias for Int64, `float` for Single, the list for C# [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).

It's also worth noting that even if you had a method returning something other than an int, say, a long, two methods signatures can't differ *only* by return value.

Comment: No problem.  It can be easy to have something not work as expected when you bounce back between different languages.  Old habits die hard, I suppose.  Glad I could help.